# List of AD names and login names

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have the following PS script against Active Directory:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter 'Name -like "Jon Doe" -Properties "SamAccountName" | Select SamAccountName
```

What I would really like is to adapt this query against Active Directory and get a full list of all Names and SamAccountNames on AD, like the following:

[image]

Comment: Remove the filter and select samaccountname and name?

Comment: @AdminOfThings thanks - new it was likely something simple but as PS still feel like rocket science to me thought I'd better post the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As below:

```
get-aduser -filter * | select samaccountname,name
```